# Stopping Internet from going through VPN

Tags: untagged

At home that has a large number of hard drives connected to it that I want to be able to access from my laptop wherever I go. To sort this, I've installed Windows Server 8 Beta with Microsoft's VPN server running and I can connect to it from almost any other point on the internet and can access my files perfectly. The only irritating thing is that my requests to normal internet resources are getting routed through the VPN server too. Can anyone tell me how turn that off?

Comment: "Anything in a home environment" is specifically off topic per the [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq).

Comment: @sysadmin1138 even when it pertains to professional grade server software being used foolishly in a home environment?

Comment: [Indeed](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1049/changing-the-faq-home-networks). The key bit is, "...in a professional context", which we've further scoped away from professional development (see bullet point under Not About for education), which is why most of us have this stuff at home.

Comment: @sysadmin1138 Ah, sorry for the confusion, I didn't read the FAQ enough. Thanks for telling me though, I was unaware

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the TCP/IP settings for the VPN connection, uncheck "Use default gateway on remote network".